# How to display a website/redmine on TFS Dashboard

Tags: tfs, redmine

I am currently building a TFS-Dashboard (TFS2015-on premise). We are still using redmine as our ticketing system. I want to get an overview of open tickets per release and display that in the TFS dashboard but cannot seem to find a fitting addin. Great would be an addin for Redmine, but I would also settle for a possiblity to display a webpage. I tried the iframe addin but it would not install:
`30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - -------------------------------------------
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Initializing Install...
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Erweiterungsdetails...
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Identifier      : iframe-dashboard-widget
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Name            : Iframe Dashboard Widget
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Author          : areve
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Version         : 1.0.11
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Description     : A dashboard widget to show an Iframe in TFS/VSTS.
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Locale          : en-US
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   MoreInfoURL     : 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Unterstützte Produkte : 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -           Version : 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 -   Verweise        : 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - 
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Er wird nach passenden Produkten gesucht...
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - Globaler Pfad
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - ssms
30.05.2017 11:04:29 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: Diese Erweiterung kann auf den derzeit installierten Produkten nicht installiert werden.
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()`

Can you recommend an addin or solution to the install-problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any official plugins or something similar for combining TFS and  Redmine for now.

You could [add a uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?query=Be%20able%20to%20get%20installed%20TFS%20version%20(including%20TFS2015%2FTFS2017)%20by%20using%20TFS%20API%20or%20Rest%20API) or vote for [Help --- service hook for redmine](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16801459-help-service-hook-for-redmine), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

To integrate you will either have to roll your own or buy a tool. Such as [Takstop](https://www.tasktop.com/) which devote to your software integration flows, or [Cloudpipes](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/redmine/team-foundation-server).

Comment: Thank you, I am going to use the iframe-extension for now. I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The error I got above was due to a rookie mistake - instead of uploading the extension to the TFS-webui I double-clicked it in the file system.